# Access to page control from another View Controller to forward the page

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol

I use this [page](https://www.seemuapps.com/page-view-controller-tutorial-with-page-dots) to make a page control for an on-boarding page. In the other view controller, I have a button, I want when user click on the button, the page control should forward to the next page. 
The view controller that contain this button is connected to the page control with a segue 
let's say this is the action of the button

```
 @IBAction func pressNextBtn(_ sender: OButton) {

}
```

and here is the prepare segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "welcome" {
        if let welcomePage = segue.destination as? welcomePageViewController {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the page controller

```
class welcomePageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {


    lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newVc(viewController: "welcome"), self.newVc(viewController: "apperance")]
}()


func forwardPage(){
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    forwardPage()
}





func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil

    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
}
```

}

could anyone help me how to add action for  this next btn to change the page in the page control?
thank you so much

Comment: you can use NotificationCenter to post a notication which the other controller listens to and acts upon.

Comment: there should be a simpler way, i think

Comment: notifications is used for 1 to many not for 1 to 1 which is best for delegate/callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a delegate here

```
weak var delegate:WelcomePageViewController!

 @IBAction func pressNextBtn(_ sender: OButton) {
    // this 
    delegate.setViewControllers([delegate.orderedViewControllers[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // or
    delegate.goToNext() // and add logic there 
} 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "welcome" {
        if let welcomePage = segue.destination as? WelcomePageViewController {
           delegate = welcomePage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank  you so much, but i get this error in the delegate.setViewControllers.. line.    Expression type '@lvalue [UIViewController]' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the problem by modifying some codes based of the code that you gave me. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

@Sh_Khan thanks for your help, 
here is my latest code; exactly like your code:

```
weak var delegate:WelcomePageViewController!

@IBAction func pressNextBtn(_ sender: OButton) { 
delegate.setViewControllers([delegate.orderedViewControllers[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "welcome" {
    if let welcomePage = segue.destination as? WelcomePageViewController {
       delegate = welcomePage
    }
}
}
```